# Move the BrowserWindow to the bottom right

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I want to ask if there's method dynamically set the position or move the Browser Window to the bottom right?

```
BrowserWindow.setPosition(x, y)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use **[the screen API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/screen)**, and use a fixed with to offset from the edge of the screen:

```
let display = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay();
let width = display.bounds.width;
win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 600,
  x: width - 600,
  y: 0
});
```